# Why my .mov video not showing any video but just audio is playbacked?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, media-player

I'm learning & going through some tutorials in .mov format, but for some videos I cannot see any videos, but listen to just audios...

I'm running those through [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc) & [Media Player Classic Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/)

VLC just gives me audio, but no video.
& Media Player Classic Home Cinema gives me this error first, then just plays me the audio (see below)

[Superuser barred me from posting pics here by a newbie]

Comment: We need to know the error before we can help. Also, what does VLC show when you display media information, especially the codec tab?

Comment: It's probably a codec problem although i've yet to encounter a file that would not render in VLC. I would try to open this mov file in default movie player on Windows. I think it might work.

Comment: I agree with mnmnc above, it's most likely some sort of codec issue. As for the screenshot, you can either re-type the error text into the question, or you can post the screenshot anywhere on the Internet and simply include a link to it. If the screenshot is legitimate, someone will edit it into your question.